# jquery 1.3.2 initial load fails on (document).ready in ie8, but works on refresh

Tags: jquery, onload

using jquery 1.3.2.min, ui.1.7.3.min & main.js with the script functions. I have a strange behavior on ie8.

When I load the page initially the scripts all download fully, however the JQ does not fire

```
SCRIPT16389: Failed    
jquery.132.min.js, line 19 character 5841
```

three conditions can change this behavior

1. refresh the page and it works fine
2. add an alert as the first line and it also works fine.
3. including the main.js in the page itself rather than an include

for example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      alert("now works!);
```

any theories or suggestions, as the code on the reload or alert works 100%

thx Art